# How do I pipe command output to curl

Tags: curl, pipe

I am using curl to post some urlencoded content to a URL, and I want the content of the curl command to come from a pipe. Basically...

`... | curl -s --data-urlencode '{\"text\":\"$PIPE_RESULT\"}' http://...`

I thought $0 might work, but I get a invalid_payload error with the simple text of:

`echo "http://www.example.com" | curl -s --data-urlencode '{"text\":\"$0\"}' https:/...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xargs to the rescue!

```
echo "http://www.example.com" | \
xargs -I moo curl -s --data-urlencode '{"text\":\"moo\"}' https://example.com
```

The 'moo' string given to xargs means that it will replace 'moo' in the following string with the contents it read from stdin.